# Sent to specific clients/groups?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

Let's say I'm making a chat, is it possible to sent messages to specific users and particularly groups of users? Can I hook up ID's to clients that have been logged on and groups that have been started, so I can sent messages to the server using these ID's and the server just sends these messages to the correct people? The chat app would look much like a chat from an MMO game where you can receive broadcast (from entire network), room, private, group and party messages in the same window.

Also I have a database behind this, is it possible I can use this for the above? Like using the same user ID's as in the database? Likewise I'm storing groups with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can create rooms or even private chats using web sockets, there are lots of examples out there. I have only used Socket.IO and they are finally 1.0 production ready. Check their docs: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

```
// Join    
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});

// Emit
io.to('some room').emit('some event'):
```